# Problema con Sqflite

Tags: flutter

No se porque da ese error.... tengo 4 bases de datos hechas de la misma forma .... alguien me puede explicar?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código y el error los puedes compartir como texto y es más fácil revisarlos e incluso intentar replicar el problema. Piensa por ejemplo, en quienes tienen alguna discapacidad y usan asistentes de lectura para usar el sitio (que es un caso real).

Comment: lo tendré en cuenta para la próxima

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se da porque estás usando una palabra reservada (`CHECK`) como nombre de un campo.

No sé si, como en otros DBMS, puedas usar el nombre de campo entre comillas para indicar que es un literal y no la palabra reservada. Yo en tu lugar, cambiaría el nombre del campo.

Comment: era eso ... gracias para la próxima procurare no utilizar las palabras reservadas ... y leer la documentación xd